# Access boot menu from windows 7

Tags: boot, keyboard

I busted my keyboard on my laptop, and now my computer rarely starts since it doesnt ignore this problem when booting. So what i want to do, is to disable my keyboard from the boot menu. But I cant access the boot menu since my keyboard doesnt work. I have an addtional keybaord via USB but that one doesnt work before windows is booted.

So in short, what I want is to access my laptops boot menu now when im on windows via cmd, but im not sure how to do it.

Comment: What make and model is the lap-top and what is the BIOS ?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking to do is virtually impossible.

I say "virtually" because in theory you could edit a BIOS image with a hex editor and, if you knew where the hex codes were for the keyboard option, tweak the correct setting before flashing that image to the CMOS. However, that's only if your BIOS supports being flashed from a specialized software tool in Windows. I've done it on some Acer laptops to overwrite a password protected BIOS.

Check the specifics of how to interact with your BIOS on the BIOS manufacturer's website. What BIOS is it? Phoenix? Version number?

**EDIT:** Phoenix does have a tool to edit their BIOS. It's dubious if you can acquire it legally if you're not an OEM manufacturer with a contract with them. There is [a lot of information on the webs](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22phoenix+bios+editor%22) about editing Phoenix BIOS images, but I'll leave you to research it or someone else to go into that depth.

Comment: I believe it is a Phoenix, version number im not sure since I'll need to reboot and that could mean that I wont be able to come back here again :) :(.

Comment: @repsak: Have a look around for a phoenix bios editor

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the broken keyboard would be so much easier than the other "solutions" suggested.

There's probably a used part on ebay or craig's list for $20, plus 15 minutes finding the service manual on the manufacturer's website... 5 screws and it's good as new.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a way to access BIOS and then enable USB devices from there (http://suhastech.com/bios/enable-usb-keyboard-support-in-system-bios/) but it's useful for PCs. I guess that solution will not be suitable to your case.

But as far as I know, you'll be able to access BIOS using your keyboard... and if it's broken maybe you'll have to replace it if you find replacement parts.